# Whats the matter with this apache config?

Tags: apache

DocumentRoot "mypath"

```
    ServerName workspace
    ServerAlias *.workspace

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory "mypath">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On

      # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
      # getting no_script_name to work
      # RewriteBase /

      #redirect to domain.com if www. is given
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
      RewriteRule ^.*$           http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index_dev.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
    </Directory>


    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
```

if I try to access `mysite/module1`, it works. But as soon as only `mysite` it fails. Why? (Access forbidden!). Its Win7

Comment: Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: there is no .htaccess